# SNS subplots using loops

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, seaborn

I want to loop through the list g to have subplots using

```
ax = sns.countplot(x='salary', hue="left", data=df)

g = ['salary', 'Gender ','Marrital Status', 'EducationLevel', 'Overtime', 
     'Stock Level', 'Experience ', 'Role', 'Business Travel']
```

`g` is a list of categories in a dataframe showing employee churn. I have attribute `left` as my label and want to plot the categories in the list `g` against my label

My attempt:

```
g = ['salary', 'Gender ', 'Marrital Status', 'EducationLevel', 'Overtime', 'Stock Level', 'Experience ', 'Role', 'Business Travel'] 
for i in g: 
    ax = sns.countplot(x=i, hue="left", data=df)
```

Comment: Could you provide some context? Is g a list of categories you're drawing data from? Where is the data coming from? What have you tried so far?

Comment: These details are really helpful. Could you add them to the question itself, so that they're more visible to other people? Also, what does `left` mean?

Comment: Thank your Jorge Perez let me do exactly that. to answer your question 'left' is one of the columns in the dataframe indicating churm per category

Comment: Thanks for editing the question! Did you get an error when you tried your attempt? Or what happened?

Comment: I have also tried this:

Comment: g = ['satisfaction_level', 'last_evaluation', 'number_project',
       'average_montly_hours', 'time_spend_company', 'Work_accident', 'left',
       'promotion_last_5years', 'Department', 'salary', 'Gender ',
       'Marrital Status', 'EducationLevel', 'Overtime', 'Stock Level',
       'Experience ', 'Role', 'Business Travel']
for ax, i in zip(g, df):
    ax = sns.countplot(x=i,data=df, hue='left')
    print(ax)

Comment: Jorge Perex am not getting an error am not getting the output i want... i want individual plots of each item in the list but its only giving me out for the last item in the list

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
g = ['salary', 'Gender ', 'Marrital Status', 'EducationLevel', 'Overtime', 'Stock Level', 'Experience ', 'Role', 'Business Travel'] 
ax = [sns.countplot(x=i, hue="left", data=df) for i in g]
```

Comment: Jorge Perez it is giving me the same output as my attempt. it is iterating through the items in the list but only plotting the last item

Comment: Hi Jorge Perez, i did manage to find a solution for. below is what i tried and worked. Thank you for your assistance and efforts

Comment: ANSWER:g = ['Department', 'salary', 'Gender ',
       'Marrital Status', 'EducationLevel', 'Overtime', 'Stock Level',
       'Experience ', 'Role', 'Business Travel']
count = 0
while count < len(g):
    ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.countplot(df[g[count]], hue=df['left'])